# mySQL: how to update table and fields dependent on values in other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a database with hinky data in it.  Fortunately it is consistently hinky so I should be able to run some nice SQL on it and clean it up.  Here's the story:

```
Table 'uc_products':
nid   model
1     asdf
2     qwer
3     ghjk

Table 'uc_product_stock':
nid   sku 
1     asdf
22    qwer
34    ghjk
```

So you can see that model=sku, and nid=nid.  The table uc_products has all the **correct** data in it, and uc_product_stock is the one with bad data (nid's that don't match the sku's).  I want to look through uc_product_stock and for each entry, compare to uc_product:

- Where model==sku & nid==nid : yeah!  Data is good!
- Where model==sku & nid!=nid : boo!  Bad data, so uc_stock_product.nid should be updated to match the value in uc_product.nid

[I guess a more brute force way to do this would be to match each row on SKU/model and reset each uc_product_stock.nid to match the uc_product.nid -- the principal being that the wrong ones would be corrected and the right ones would be reset to the same value and stay right.  I am open to that if you think it's the best answer, but it makes me feel a little funny.  I don't like to mess with data that is already right.]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just run a simple update statement like this:

```
UPDATE uc_product_stock a
  SET a.nid = (SELECT MIN(b.nid)
                 FROM uc_products b
                WHERE b.sku = a.sku)
```

Comment: Thanks!  The "b" didn't work (I think because it was called before it was declared?) but I just swapped it out for "UPDATE uc_product_stock SET uc_product_stock.nid = (SELECT MIN(uc_products.nid) FROM uc_products WHERE uc_products.model = uc_product_stock.sku)" and all was well!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but this should work:

```
UPDATE uc_product_stock AS s 
INNER JOIN uc_product AS p ON p.model=s.sku SET s.sku=p.model 
WHERE p.nid!=s.nid AND p.model=s.sku
```